# A proof of limits relating to a uniformly convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

> Suppose that ${F_n}$ converges uniformly to $F$ on $(a,b)$. Prove that
>   if $a < x_0 < b$ and $L_n = \lim_{x\to{x_0}} F_n(x)$ exists and is
>   finite for all $n$, then $L = \lim_{n\to\infty} L_n$ exists and is
>   finite and $\lim_{x\to{x_0}} F(x) = L$.

I don't know where to start on this. Are there any properties of uniform convergence that I can exploit to prove this? I haven't been able to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and find some $N$ such that $|F_{n}(x)-F(x)|<\epsilon$, for all $x\in(a,b)$ and $n\geq N$. So for fixed $n\geq N$, we have 
\begin{align*}
F_{n}(x)-\epsilon<F(x)<F_{n}(x)+\epsilon,~~~~x\in(a,b)
\end{align*}
taking limit $x\rightarrow x_{0}$, one has
\begin{align*}
-\infty<L_{n}-\epsilon\leq\liminf_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}F(x)\leq\limsup_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}F(x)\leq L_{n}+\epsilon<\infty,
\end{align*}
in particular, $-\infty<\liminf_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}F(x)\leq\limsup_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}F(x)<\infty$.

Now taking $n\rightarrow\infty$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n}L_{n}-\epsilon\leq\liminf_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}F(x)\leq\limsup_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}F(x)\leq\liminf_{n}L_{n}+\epsilon,
\end{align*}
taking $\epsilon\downarrow 0$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n}L_{n}\leq\liminf_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}F(x)\leq\limsup_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}F(x)\leq\liminf_{n}L_{n},
\end{align*}
we conclude that $\lim_{n}L_{n}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}F(x)$.

Comment: A quick question on notation: for the last step, are you taking the limit as epsilon approaches 0 from the right hand side?

Comment: Yes, because initially we have $\epsilon>0$, right sided limit is the correct one that we can do it.